# Recognize Whether an Update is Via the API and which Fields Are Mapped

Tags: apex, trigger, soap-api, data-loader

Once a month I update a couple of currency fields on accounts via a data loader.  There are two corresponding date fields that show, after workflow-rule updates, when the previous fields were last updated (e.g. update Date__c if ISCHANGED(Currency__c) ).

The requirement is for those date fields to be updated in this scenario, *regardless* of whether the currency fields actually changed (since sometimes they don't from one month to the next).

I know this can easily be done with an additional field, adding its change as a criterion in the workflow rules, and then arbitrarily updating it in the same mass update as the other fields - but that's not ideal in my opinion.

So I wondered if there is a way in Apex to recognize whether updates (or any DML for that matter) are being carried out via the API, i.e. a data loader, and which fields were mapped for update in the job.

Then I can do something like:

```
if(update is via API && mapped field == Currency__c){
    //Do Something
}
```

Any thoughts, ideas or insight?

Thanks

Comment: Even if there is a way to do this, it seems like a bad idea - it will basically mean you have to modify the code to take it out if you ever want to use Data Loader to do something other than this update.  I wonder if you can link Data Loader to a REST Resource class?

Comment: short answer is NOPE.  You could have the Data Loader job always run as a specific user (headless) so your Apex would recognize the source of the transaction

Comment: Why not just update the updated date field during the data load along with the currency?